# Virtualizing WrapPanel

Tags: wpf

Does WPF 4 contain also a virtualizing WrapPanel or is it easy to make one deriving from an existing panel. I want to make an address-view such as outlook has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its possible to implement a WrapPanel with full virtualization(on both directions), but check this out : http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's easily possible if you have fixed-size items - with variable sized items it's doable, but takes a little more guesswork (you can't always size the scrollbar correctly).

Comment: This implementation on codeplex uses a "guessing" mechanism to virtualize one direction(items with arbitrary size). Maybe its possible to do the same in two directions if either the Height or Width of the items are fixed(I havent tought much about it).